# Laravel - Authorization to patch function

Tags: php, laravel

i have this PATCH function but i need to add some form of authorization to ensure you can only edit/update a film that is associated with the current user, can i get some help on how to add this

controller function:

```
 public function update(string $id)
{
    $this->user = Auth::user();
    $this->film = film:findOrFail($id);

    return $this->film->toJson();
}
```

I've looked at the laravel docs at the validation section and seen this example

```
 $validatedData = $request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unque:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

i then added my own validation at the top of the file

```
protected $validation = [
    'name' => 'string',
    'description' => 'new description'
];
```

im a little lost on how i implement authorization to ensure only a current user can update a film?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on what you're asking but generally $validation/$request->validate is done for FORM validation. If you want to validate the user validating, what you can do is pass the user id into the function/ public function update($userid) and compare it with Auth::user(). From here filter out all users that are associated with this user and voila, you have your solution

Comment: also, i think what you're looking for is more towards *Permissions* not Validation :)

Comment: yep, no worries! you're new to Laravel. But yeah, I think you're looking for permission. you can manually allow a permission pass here. Basically use an if else statement to do it, i'll post it below so you can see an EXAMPLE of how you can handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is not a form validation, but a User Authorization (as in the comments). So you should have a look at the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization). In your case you should write a `FilmPolicy` that may look like to this (I will skip the registration part... It can be easily understood from the docs):

```php
class FilmPolicy {

    /**
     * Determine if the given film can be updated by the user.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update(User $user, Film $film)
    {
        return $user->id === $film->user_id; // Or whatever is your foreign key
    }

}
```

Then you should update your controller in order to handle the authorization as follow:

```php
public function update(string $id)
{

    $this->film = film::findOrFail($id);

    $this->authorize('update', $this->film);

    return $this->film->toJson();
}
```

Since this method simply throws an exception, you can have a more elaborate response as explained [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#policy-responses)

Answer (score 0):

Ok basically, to enable what you need in a simple way, what you can do is this;

First pass the 'user_id' to the controller.

```
public function update(string $id, $userid)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $id = $user->id;
    if($id == $userid)
    {
        $this->user = Auth::user();
        $this->film = film::findOrFail($id);

        return $this->film->toJson();
    }else{
        return "Not Authorized";
    }

}
```

If im not misunderstanding your question, this basically allows only the user who is logged in to update his film. if he goes into any other profile, the id's would mismatch and thus return a not authorized prompt.

Comment: you're a star thank you for the quick response and the help for this! sorry for being a noob and explaining it wrong

Comment: No worries, refer to the answer by @ilgala as well, it's a better insight on user authorization when you have the time to look into it. the method i used is basically a hack in a way